# Excel VBA is throwing "type mismatch" error on a preceding line of code based on a different line of code

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

Sorry if that makes no sense, but here is my code that works:

```
Const DSD_WS_NAME As String = "DSD"
Dim lRow As Long
Dim sName As String
Dim bEODSD As Boolean

lRow = lRow + 1
sName = Sheets(DSD_WS_NAME).Cells(lRow, 8).Value
If (sName = "") Then
    bEODSD = True
End If
```

I'm trying to set the condition to exit a While loop, and while this code runs, it turns out an empty string is not necessarily a good indicator for end of data.

Here's the thing, if I change the string in the If statement to have some content (e.g. "A"), then the PREVIOUS line of code throws a type mismatch error.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

EDIT: I just tried casting the whole Sheets line of code as a string

```
sName = CStr(Sheets(DSD_WS_NAME).Cells(lRow, 8).Value)
```

And now I get "Application-defined or object defined error" [1004]

EDIT 2:
If I step through the code using F8, it works fine.  Pressing F5 brings up the aforementioned errors.  This is something that will have to run overnight as it is, but it would probably take days if I have to glue down the F8 key to make it work :/

Comment: my vba is a little rusty but try `sName = Cstr(Sheets(DSD_WS_NAME).Cells(lRow, 8).Value)` to convert the value to a string.

Comment: Debug each part of that line and make sure you add the explicit workbook reference. Does the error occur without the loop?

Comment: Try before that lineto use Debug.Print Sheets(DSD_WS_NAME) Is Nothing

Comment: Agree with @QHarr, but my money's on that unqualified `Sheets` object - and probably a different active workbook.

Comment: ^^ mhm quite likely

Comment: Did you add the workbook reference in front? e.g. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DSD_WS_NAME)  ? Change ThisWorkbook if required to correct Workbooks reference.

Comment: I have it working now but I'm not really sure why.  I use this same logic somewhere else in the code too, and I changed that "sheets" line of code to also be cast as a string (CStr).  So it runs now, but I don't recall ever having to do this before.

Thanks for the ThisWorkbook suggestion, but the sheet object is defined as I can get the name of it in Debug.Print statements.  It's also the only workbook I have open at the moment.

Comment: I suggest you break on error without that cstr and check what value is coming in on the line you have now identified as being a problem.

Comment: @QHarr break on error won't work because it won't even begin to run the code before throwing the error.  If I step through it line by line with the debugger, everything works fine.  It honestly feels like a problem with Excel VBA itself.  Not only this debugger scenario, but how can changing one line of code cause the previous line of code to suddenly not be okay?  Thanks for all your quick responses though.  It really helped me think and that's much appreciated.